# HTTPERR log: Request_Cancelled (while troubleshooting WCF service)

Tags: c#, wcf, http, http.sys

I am trying to troubleshoot a "connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error on a WCF client accessing a WCF self-hosted service. I was looking at the httperr logs in System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR on the service-side machine and each time I see that error on my client, I see entries in the log with my service's endpoint URI. The reason is "Request_Cancelled".

I can't find anything anywhere about what that reason signifies. I can guess, but I'd like to know for sure, as it must have some relation to the errors I am seeing in my client.

What is "Request_Cancelled" in the HTTPERR log? And as a bonus, can you shed any extra light on my WCF issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request_cancelled might be a timeout.

By default it should be

```
OpenTimeout - 1 minute
CloseTimeout - 1 minute
SendTimeOut - 1 minute
ReceiveTimeout - 10 minute.
```

Try set these settings in your web.config. 
It will add further logging to your web service.

At your system.serviceModel section

```
<system.serviceModel>

....

    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
    </diagnostics>     

....
</system.serviceModel>
```

and add system.diagnostics section. It will save a log to c:\temp\wcfServiceLog.svc

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="4"/>
  </switches>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\wcfServiceLog.svc" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Well, I've underestimated the power of the trace logs. They showed me the exception that the service was really throwing, and the problem was how I was wrapping it in a FaultException which was causing the service to drop the request altogether (hence, Request_Cancelled). Thanks.

Comment: This happens not only for timeouts, it happened to us when we tried to serialize DateTime.MinValue. App worked everywhere except the places which are ahead of UTC timezone. This helped us a lot to find root cause