# "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent" over http but not https

Tags: windows, web-services, http, iis, server

I recently migrated a .net web service from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2. When trying to access the web service help page the browser will wait for the server request but nothing ever happens. The request just hangs and I never get a timeout or any other status code. When checking the HTTPERR logs on the server, I see that the request was cancelled and has no status code. (See Below)

```
2015-06-02 15:20:49 11.127.2.128 50755 11.113.4.14 56272 HTTP/1.1 GET /HumanResourceServices/1_0_0/help/ - 2 Request_Cancelled HumanResourceServices
```

I reviewed this question [HTTPERR log: Request_Cancelled (while troubleshooting WCF service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725258/httperr-log-request-cancelled-while-troubleshooting-wcf-service) and did the suggested logging. The svc log file is generated but it stays at 0 byte size and never changes. I checked the worker processes in IIS and it gets a request for the site but I do not see request when I go to "View Current Request" for it. It seems like my request is never getting processed, cancelled and the server never responds with a status code. To make things even more interesting, if I access the same site over https, it works! So this is only happening when I try to access over http. Any advice or suggestions on ways to further troubleshoot this is much appreciated.

UPDATE --

I was able to get the log working. The request is being cancelled because the application is throwing an exception. The error message is "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent." Does anyone have any idea why I would be getting this error over http but not over https? Also note, this is only happening on the new Windows 2008 R2 server. Our old server Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6.0) did not have this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was an oversight on my part. The application pool was set to integrated when it should have been classic. Once it was switched, issue went away.