# Web api 2 controller in web forms application has connection closed with Request_Cancelled

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, webforms, asp.net-web-api2, iis-10

I have an Asp.Net Webforms application, and am trying to add an webapi controller to return a pdf. The route is being hit, but Chrome says nothing is returned. Postman shows my test document.  I created a test webform project, added the controller to it, and everything works from there (i.e. chrome downloads and displays my test document as does chrome). I am using the exact same code in both (attribute base routing).

I did some investigation with Powershell, Postman and Fiddler, and have discovered that Powershell and Postman will also fail if I include the Accept and Accept-Encoding headers that Chrome sends for my main project, but still succeeds with the test project.

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
```

The httperr.log has:

```
2023-07-09 21:12:40 ::1%0 61004 ::1%0 443 HTTP/2 GET /mysite/api/testapi/1 1 - - 1 Request_Cancelled DefaultAppPool TCP
2023-07-09 21:20:13 ::1%0 61120 ::1%0 443 HTTP/1.1 GET /mysite/api/testapi/1 - - - 1 Request_Cancelled DefaultAppPool TCP
```

When failing with a call from chrome and powershell

Comment: You could try to capture and analyze logs, refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734554/20058276 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58109148/20058276.